# How to write a query showing associated record growth, week after week?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Given the following two tables & fields:

```
companies (id, created_at, title)
company_members (id, company_id, created_at, member_info)
```

I would like to write a query that shows how the company_members grow over time, from the week the company was created, and then showing week by week until the current week.

**Example of desired results:**

[image: Example of desired data]

The example above should be showing, for example, that in Dec 6th, on Week 1 100 members were created. By Week 2 (there are now 110, 110% of members)

How can I get started on this?

Comment: I just realized, it's possible week 1 can be greater than 100%. for example. If I create the workspace on Monday with 10 users, that's 100% in week 1. In Day 2 of Week 1, if I add more users, now week 1 is above 100%

Comment: If I'm interpreting your picture correctly, the spreadsheet is showing impossible data. The first row is showing that each week you added 10% original week 1 number.  This amount added would be _less than_ 10% of the week 2 number, and significantly less than 10% of the week 6 number, so the following rows should show smaller numbers.

Comment: In your example of desired result, do the rows correspond to the same company id ? And if so, why do you need several rows for the same company id ? One row should be sufficient to cover your need "how the company_members grow over time, from the week the company was created, and then showing week by week until the current week". Please explain more in detail the way to calculate the desired results.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution to calculate the growth over time, per company_id, from the week the company was created, and then showing week by week until the current week :

```
WITH list AS
(
SELECT c.id AS company_id
     , cm.created_at - mod((EXTRACT('dow' FROM cm.created_at) + 6) :: integer, 7) AS week -- first day of the week associated to cm.created_at
     , count(*) AS count
  FROM companies AS c
 INNER JOIN company_members AS cm
    ON cm.created_at >= c.created_at
 GROUP BY c.id, week
)
SELECT l.company_id
     , l.week
     , to_char(sum(l.count) OVER w / first_value(l.count) OVER w, '99999V99 %') AS growth
  FROM list AS l
 RIGHT JOIN 
     ( SELECT company_id
            , generate_series(min(week), now() :: date , interval '7 days') AS week
         FROM list
        GROUP BY company_id
     ) AS w
    ON w.company_id = l.company_id
   AND w.week = l.week
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY l.company_id ORDER BY l.week)
 ORDER BY l.company_id, l.week
```

see the test result in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=a72073d0e5b38dcc4451fddf1e036100).

The way you want to display the result is your question is not clear for the moment.